# iOS 6 UIActivityViewController - how to present Share Action Sheet with local language?

Tags: ios, localization, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

How to change built-in labels such as  "Mail", "Weibo", "Copy", "Cancel" on the popup sharing  -panel into local language?  Thanks!

Comment: Check the accepted answer here, it may solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13562814/twitter-preview-sheet-appears-in-english-instead-of-language-device-on-ios-6-usi?rq=1

Comment: Thanks！That accepted answer didn't solve the problem.  Instead, after many hours, I found out the following did work--Add "Localized resources can be mixed" and set its value as "Yes" in Info.plist.  Hope this would help others :)

Comment: @user2276520 make it as an answer and accept it to get notify by others quickly.

Answer (score 9):

"Add "Localized resources can be mixed" and set its value as "Yes" in Info.plist." Also solved my problem! Thank you!

Comment: Not sufficient : don't know why but only Save the file was still in english, among other labels translated. As Alexander said, use Localization native development region is the solution

Answer (score 1):

My app has 1 language Russian, so it helps me: 
In Info.plist
For example add key "Localization native development region" = "ru"(your locale)